# Splitting up a string into tokens, then displaying them in order of appearance in the string

Tags: java

I am writing a program to read a string, which contains code in text form. The program scans input searching keyword tokens and printing them in order of appearance. However it misses keywords defined in the `getKeyword()` method. The order of appearance is also unexpected.

Apologies in advanced for the code, I am new to programming.

```
public class Testing{
enum OperatorToken {
```

//tokens go here

```
}


public static String inputString = "public class HelloWorld";



private static void stringOutput() {
    String[] lines = inputString.split("\\r?\\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    {
        String line = lines[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++)
        {
            TokenType tokenTypeChar = getOP(line.charAt(j));
            TokenType tokenTypeSymbol = getSymbol(line.charAt(j));

            if (tokenTypeChar != null){
                System.out.printf("Line %d: %s, %s", i + 1, tokenTypeChar.name(), line.charAt(j));
                System.out.println(" ");
            }else if (tokenTypeSymbol != null){
                System.out.printf("Line %d: %s, %s", i + 1, tokenTypeSymbol.name(), line.charAt(j));
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }

        TokenType tokenTypeString = getOP(line);
        TokenType tokenTypeKeyword = getKeyword(line);

        if (tokenTypeKeyword != null)
        {
            System.out.printf("Line %d: %s, %s", i + 1, tokenTypeKeyword.name(), SubString);
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

        else if (tokenTypeString != null)
        {
            System.out.printf("Line %d: %s, %s", i + 1, tokenTypeString.name(), SubString);
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

    }
}

private static TokenType getOP(char ch) {
    switch (ch) {
        case '+':
            return TokenType.OP_ADD;
        case '-':
            return TokenType.OP_SUBTRACT;
        case '/':
            return TokenType.OP_DIVIDE;
        case '*':
            return TokenType.OP_MULTIPLY;
        // more
    }
    return null;
}

public static TokenType getSymbol(char ch)
{

    switch (ch) {
        case '(':
            return TokenType.LEFT_PAREN;
        case ')':
            return TokenType.RIGHT_PAREN;
        case '{':
            return TokenType.LEFT_BRACE;
        case '}':
            return TokenType.RIGHT_BRACE;
        case '[':
            return TokenType.LEFT_BRACKET;
        case ']':
            return TokenType.RIGHT_BRACKET;
        case ';':
            return TokenType.SEMICOLON;
        case ':':
            return TokenType.COLON;
        case ',':
            return TokenType.COMMA;

    }

    return null;

}

public static TokenType getOP(String str)
{

    if (str.contains("<="))
    {
        SubString = "<=";
        return TokenType.OP_LESSEQUAL;
    }

    else if (str.contains(">="))
    {
        SubString = ">=";
        return TokenType.OP_GREATEREQUAL;
    }

    else if (str.contains("=="))
    {
        SubString = "==";
        return TokenType.OP_EQUAL;
    }

    else if (str.contains("!="))
    {
        SubString = "!=";
        return TokenType.OP_NOTEQUAL;
    }

    else if (str.contains("&&"))
    {
        SubString = "&&";
        return TokenType.OP_AND;
    }

    else if (str.contains("||"))
    {
        SubString = "||";
        return TokenType.OP_OR;
    }

    return null;

}


public static TokenType getKeyword(String str)
{
    if (str.contains("if"))
    {
        SubString = "if";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_IF;
    }

    else if (str.contains("else"))
    {
        SubString = "else";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_ELSE;
    }

    else if (str.contains("while"))
    {
        SubString = "while";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_WHILE;
    }

    else if (str.contains("return"))
    {
        SubString = "return";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_RETURN;
    }

    else if (str.contains("main"))
    {
        SubString = "main";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_MAIN;
    }

    else if (str.contains("int"))
    {
        SubString = "int";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_INT;
    }

    else if (str.contains("double"))
    {
        SubString = "double";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_DOUBLE;
    }
    else if (str.contains("String"))
    {
        SubString = "String";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_STRING;
    }

    else if (str.contains("boolean"))
    {
        SubString = "boolean";
        return TokenType.BOOLEAN;
    }

    else if (str.contains("public"))
    {
        SubString = "public";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_PUBLIC;
    }

    else if (str.contains("class"))
    {
        SubString = "class";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_CLASS;
    }

    else if (str.contains("void"))
    {
        SubString = "void";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_VOID;
    }

    else if (str.contains("for"))
    {
        SubString = "for";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_FOR;
    }

    else if (str.contains("case"))
    {
        SubString = "case";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_CASE;
    }

    else if (str.contains("static"))
    {
        SubString = "static";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_STATIC;
    }

    else if (str.contains("break"))
    {
        SubString = "break";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_BREAK;
    }

    else if (str.contains("continue"))
    {
        SubString = "continue";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_CONTINUE;
    }

    else if (str.contains("default"))
    {
        SubString = "default";
        return TokenType.KEYWORD_DEFAULT;
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    stringOutput();


    }
}

}
```

Current output:

```
Line 1: LEFT_BRACE, { 
Line 1: KEYWORD_PUBLIC, public 
Line 2: LEFT_PAREN, ( 
Line 2: LEFT_BRACKET, [ 
Line 2: RIGHT_BRACKET, ] 
Line 2: RIGHT_PAREN, ) 
Line 2: LEFT_BRACE, { 
Line 2: KEYWORD_MAIN, main 
Line 3: SEMICOLON, ; 
Line 3: KEYWORD_INT, int 
Line 4: SEMICOLON, ; 
Line 4: KEYWORD_DOUBLE, double 
Line 5: OP_ADD, + 
Line 5: OP_MULTIPLY, * 
Line 5: SEMICOLON, ; 
Line 5: KEYWORD_DOUBLE, double 
Line 6: LEFT_PAREN, ( 
Line 6: COLON, : 
Line 6: OP_ADD, + 
Line 6: RIGHT_PAREN, ) 
Line 6: SEMICOLON, ; 
Line 6: KEYWORD_INT, int 
Line 7: RIGHT_BRACE, } 
Line 8: RIGHT_BRACE, }
```

Comment: Perhaps it has been, but rather [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283478/scanner-lexing-keywords-with-antlr). @Quasease tries to build a scanner/tokenizer by hand. Just that the approach chosen won't get him very far, if you look at this example `System.out.println("System.out.println(\"The num is: \" + c)");`, how would you distinguish code from string content? Usually this stuff comes up as stage 1 of parsing, with machinery provided that generates scanner and parser given an input grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've set up your for loop, you will only print out one keyword per line. That's because you're looping through each line of text in the program and calling getKeyword once inside that loop. However it's possible that a line of code contains multiple keywords.

For example, the first line of the program has 2 keywords but when you pass that line to your getKeyword method, it will only return a single keyword:

```
getKeyword("public class HelloWorld {")
>> public
```

You could start by having an inner loop that loops through each word in the line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
    String line = lines[i];

    // Parse symbols
    for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++)
    {
        TokenType tokenTypeChar = getOP(line.charAt(j));
        TokenType tokenTypeSymbol = getSymbol(line.charAt(j));

        if (tokenTypeChar != null){
            System.out.printf("Line %d: %s, %s", i + 1, tokenTypeChar.name(), line.charAt(j));
            System.out.println(" ");
        } else if (tokenTypeSymbol != null){
            System.out.printf("Line %d: %s, %s", i + 1, tokenTypeSymbol.name(), line.charAt(j));
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }

    // Parse keywords in line
    String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
    for (String word : words)
    {
        TokenType tokenTypeKeyword = getKeyword(word);    
        if (tokenTypeKeyword != null) {
            System.out.println("Keyword found: " + tokenTypeKeyword);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might also want to do exact matches for keyword instead of doing contains. This will prevent words that look similar to keywords from matching.